# Understanding a particular For Loop

Tags: c++, loops

So I was researching C++ yesterday; looking at some example code, and trying to get the feel of things. I saw this:

```
for (bool b = true; b; )
{
    b = true;
    //Other stuff.
}
```

It's making me feel stupid because this is the first time I've seen a for loop used this way. Basically, what is this saying? What would be an equivalent while loop?

Comment: that is a truly bizarre way of expressing that.

Comment: Ew, that was in *example* code?

Comment: The b = true in the braces does nothing; it only gets called to set b to true when b is true

Answer (score 7):

It's the same as:

```
bool b = true; // 1

while(b) // 2
{
    b = true;
    //Other stuff.
    // 3
}
```

The 3 semicolon-separated parts of a for loop always correspond to the places I commented in the while loop.

Don't think of it as a clever way to save a couple lines, though.  Anyone who writes code like you saw should be taken out and shot.

Comment: Thank you; I now get the picture.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment but it doesn't just save a couple of lines, it also limits the scope of the b variable.

Comment: yeah, @tinman is right. Besides, you get a picture of how the variable of the loop is going to change in the loop, rather than having to look at top and bottom of the loop. Even if it makes it look more complicated. For example `for (int i, scanf("%d", &i); i; scanf("%d", &i)) {...}` makes much more sense to me than the `while` equivalent (although in this very particular case, I would write: `int i; while (scanf("%d", &i), i) {...}`)

Comment: I have to admit in the previous post I also wanted to show @randolph levant that those three statements could be ANY valid statement that could be placed in locations 1, 2 and 3 as karl bielefeldt has mentioned. And by any I mean any. For example this: `for (FILE *fin = fopen("some_file", "r"); network_is_working(); draw_statistics_graph()) {.../*maybe read from file, do something from network and save statistics*/...}`

Comment: @Shahbaz put it as an answer then =)

Comment: @jadarnel27: His answer was correct, I don't want to put a lot of answers for the OP that are basically all the same, just confusing the OP.

Answer (score 2):

```
do
{
  b = true;
  // Other stuff
} while(b);
```

Comment: It's wrong, a for loop checks the condition _before_ do the body

Comment: @BlackBear This may not be equivalent of for loop in general, but by given information, it is very much same as the given for loop.